# How to remove rows based on distance from an average of column and max of another column

Tags: r, dataframe

Consider this toy data frame. I would like to create a new data frame in which only rows that are below the average of "birds" and only rows that less than the two top values after the maximum value of "wolfs".So in this data frame I'll get only rows: 543,608,987,225,988,556.
I used this two lines of code for the first constrain but couldn't find a solution for the second constrain.

```
df$filt<-ifelse(df$birds<mean(df$birds),1,0)
 df1<-df1[which(df1$filt==1),]
```

How can I create the second constrain ?
Here is the toy dataframe:

```
df <- read.table(text = "userid target birds    wolfs     
                222              1        9         7 
                444              1        8         4 
                234              0        2         8 
                543              1        2         3 
                678              1        8         3 
                987              0        1         2 
                294              1        7         1 
                608              0        1         5 
                123              1        9         7 
                321              1        8         7 
                226              0        2         7 
                556              0        2         3 
                334              1        6         3 
                225              0        1         1 
                999              0        3         9 
                988              0        1         1  ",header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you explain the second constraint a bit? I do not understand what you mean with "only rows that less than the two top values after the maximum value of "wolfs""

Comment: I have a solution but it fit your desired output except that it selects also the `userid` 543.

Comment: The maximum of "wolfs" is 9 and below it there are rows with 8 and 7  so any row with values that are below those top two values whould be in the new data frame. If there were rows of 6 and 5 and no 8 or 7 than only rows that are below 5 should be included.Hope I'm mpre clear now.

Comment: @mql4beginner Do you want the `wolfs` constraint to work on the third-highest value, or the third-highest row? This would make a difference if there were duplicates among the three highest values. For example, say `wolfs` consisted of 9,8,8,7,5,3,1. Would you want only rows below 8, or only rows below 7?

Comment: Thanks @bgoldst,third-highest value..How acn evoid the problem that you showed,Is there away to add floor or some other function to make sure to include all of the rows?

Comment: @mql4beginner See my edited answer, now I believe it does what you want.

Comment: @bgoldst, Thanks a lot for adding the unique function..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
subset(df,birds < mean(birds) & wolfs < sort(unique(wolfs),decreasing=T)[3]);
##    userid target birds wolfs
## 4     543      1     2     3
## 6     987      0     1     2
## 8     608      0     1     5
## 12    556      0     2     3
## 14    225      0     1     1
## 16    988      0     1     1
```

Comment: I see that your solution has the same output as mine even though it is not as the one the OP posted. Something not clear here.

Comment: @SabDeM that's probably because you both posted identical solutions :)

Comment: Sorry @SabDeM I added 543 to the question ( I did it manuulay..)

Comment: @DavidArenburg both do not fit the required output. I though I did not understand well the question but as I see maybe I am not the one (or the OP did a mistake in expected output).

Answer (score 2):

Here a solution but maybe some constraints are not clear to me because it is fit another row respect your desired output.

```
avbi <- mean(df$birds)
ttw <- sort(df$wolfs, decreasing = T)[3]

df[df$birds < avbi & df$wolfs < ttw , ]
userid target birds wolfs
4     543      1     2     3
6     987      0     1     2
8     608      0     1     5
12    556      0     2     3
14    225      0     1     1
16    988      0     1     1
```

or with `dplyr`

```
df %>% filter(birds < avbi & wolfs < ttw)
```

Comment: Thank you SabDeM, my bad regarding #543, I edited my question and add it.